# How to convert XSL FO to XSLT template

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Using transformToFragment, by passing XSLT and XML document, I am able to achieve the PDF
For another request, I have XSL FO. Can we use XSL FO and XML document to generate the pdf?
Please advice

Using transformToFragment, by passing XSLT and XML document, I am able to achieve the PDF

For another request, I have XSL FO. Can we use XSL FO and XML document to generate the pdf?

Below is the code

```
var AppModule = function AppModule() {}; AppModule.prototype.transformUBLAndInsertIntoFrame = function (UBL, XSLT) {

let ublStr = b64DecodeUnicode(UBL?.replaceAll("\r\n", ""));    
let xsltStylesheet = b64DecodeUnicode(XSLT?.replaceAll("\r\n", ""));

const parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ublStr, "text/xml");
let resultDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("PDF Preview");       
let xsltDoc = parser.parseFromString(xsltStylesheet, "application/xml");
console.log("Serialize:" + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xsltDoc));



    let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, resultDocument); 
    resultDocument = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDocument)
    .replaceAll('&amp;', '&')
    .replaceAll('&lt;', '<') .replaceAll('&gt;','>' ) .replaceAll('&quot;','"' ) .replaceAll('&apos;',"'" ); return resultDocument; };
```

Comment: In what environment do you use that JavaScript code? Inside of the browser, it is possible to run Java 8 libraries like Apache FOP using CheerpJ 3, see https://labs.leaningtech.com/cheerpj3/getting-started/Java-library. You can write the PDF with FOP to the virtual file system of CheerpJ and from there create an object URL to load in an iframe or object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static and https://labs.leaningtech.com/cheerpj3/reference/cjFileBlob.

Comment: In Oracle VBCS, we are using Java Script. can we do the similar with Javascript?

Comment: "I am able to achieve the PDF" - What does that mean? What is the problem exactly? The question is tagged "xslt", "xslt-2.0" , "xsl-fo", but the only code in the question is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the Java code you need for transforming XML to PDF, using XSL-FO with the free implementation Apache FOP.

```
protected static byte[] format(byte[] xml, String xslTransformationName) throws PdfFormatterException
    {
        try(
            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            Fop fop = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI()).newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, os);
            StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(
                    PdfFormatter.class.getResourceAsStream(XSL_FO_DIRECTORY + xslTransformationName));
            
            var txFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            txFactory.setURIResolver((href, base) -> {
                return new StreamSource(PdfFormatter.class.getResourceAsStream(XSL_FO_DIRECTORY + href));
            }); // Allow xsl:import from the same directory as the original XSLT.
            
            Transformer tx = txFactory.newTransformer(xsl);
            tx.setErrorListener(ERROR_LISTENER);
            
            Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            tx.transform(new StreamSource(is), result);
            
            return os.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(IOException | FOPException | TransformerException e)
        {
            throw new PdfFormatterException("Error converting to PDF.", e);
        }
    }

private static final ErrorListener ERROR_LISTENER = new ErrorListener()
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdfFormatter.class);
        
        @Override
        public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
        {
            LOG.warn(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
        {
            LOG.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
        {
            LOG.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    };
```

- The Fop object comes from Apache FOP.
- XSL Transformations are stored within the JAR file in directory XSL_FO_DIRECTORY = "/xsl-fo"
- Input is an XML document as byte array, result is the PDF document as byte array, too.

Comment: Is this really "all the Java code you need"? This is not a complete class. Where are the import statements? How does this answer the question (which is not very clear and only contains JavaScript code)?